# svg stroke to remain unaffected by filter

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I am applying `<feFlood>` to a svg Element. However, upon applying, the stroke and stoke-width are getting negatively affected by that.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 600">
    <defs>
      <filter id="filt">
        <feFlood x="100" y="100" height="200" width="300" flood-color="red" flood-opacity=".5"></feFlood>        
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <rect class="bg" x="0" y="0" width="1280" height="600" fill="#EFEFEF"></rect>
    <rect class="elementRect" x="100" y="100" width="300" height="200" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" filter="url(#filt)"></rect>
</svg>
```

How can I have the filter affecting only the fill of `elementRect` and not the `stroke`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all in a filter by using a green-screen technique. Start by coloring the fill red and the stroke blue in the content, then use two color matrices to separate them out into separate layers, color them and then recombine them.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 600" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <defs>
      <filter id="filt" >
        <feFlood x="100" y="100" height="200" width="300" flood-color="red" flood-opacity=".5" result="fill-content"></feFlood>
        <feFlood x="100" y="100" height="200" width="300" flood-color="black" flood-opacity="1" result="stroke-content"></feFlood> 
        
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" result="fill-clip" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1 
                                                                0 0 0 0 1 
                                                                0 0 0 0 1 
                                                                -1 0 0 1 0"/>
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" result="stroke-clip" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1 
                                                                0 0 0 0 1 
                                                                0 0 0 0 1 
                                                                0 0 -1 1 0"/>
        
        <feComposite operator="in"  in="fill-content" in2="fill-clip" result="just-fill"/>
        <feComposite operator="in" in="stroke-content" in2="stroke-clip" result="just-stroke"/> 
        
        <feComposite operator="over" in2="just-fill" in="just-stroke"/>        
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <rect class="bg" x="0" y="0" width="1280" height="600" fill="#EFEFEF"></rect>
    <rect class="elementRect" x="100" y="100" width="300" height="200" stroke="red" fill="blue" stroke-width="5" filter="url(#filt)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Update:
If you want to replace the fill with turbulence, then you still want to select out the stroke first into a new layer, then do whatever you want with the fill, then add back the stroke. There is no way in a filter to distinguish the stroke from the fill (there was supposed to be one, but it was never implemented) - you have to color them differently so the filter can distinguish between them based on their color.

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 600" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <defs>
          <filter id="filt" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
          <feFlood x="100" y="100" height="200" width="300" flood-color="black" flood-opacity="1" result="stroke-content"></feFlood> 
          <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" result="stroke-clip" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1 
                                                                    0 0 0 0 1 
                                                                    0 0 0 0 1 
                                                                    0 0 -1 1 0"/>
          <feComposite operator="in" in="stroke-content" in2="stroke-clip" result="just-stroke"/> 
            
           
           <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" result="fill-clip" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1 
                                                                    0 0 0 0 1 
                                                                    0 0 0 0 1 
                                                                    -1 0 0 1 0"/>
            <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.1" numOctaves="3"/>
                
            <feComposite operator="over" in="just-stroke"/>        
          </filter>
        </defs>
        <rect class="bg" x="0" y="0" width="1280" height="600" fill="#EFEFEF"></rect>
        <rect class="elementRect" x="100" y="100" width="300" height="200" stroke="red" fill="blue" stroke-width="5" filter="url(#filt)"></rect>
    </svg>
```

Comment: I tried another one as `<svg width="200" height="200"><def><filter id="a">
<feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.1" numOctaves="3" seed="77"></feTurbulence>
</filter></def><rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="green" filter="url(#a)" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5"/></svg>`. It is also affecting the stoke. I don't have a good grasp on filters yet. But what is the easiest way (without duplicating the svg object) to not have the stroke affected by any filter whatsoever?

Comment: I think you might need to read a few tutorials on how SVG filters work. That turbulence primitive replaces the entire filter region with random turbulence - so all the original content (SourceGraphic) is thrown away.  You want to select out the stroke into a separate layer FIRST before you do anything else. Then add the stroke back at the end. I'll update the answer for this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use a filter, you could separate the fill from the stroke, only applying the filter to the `elementRect` that represents the fill.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 600">
    <defs>
      <filter id="filt">
        <feFlood x="100" y="100" height="200" width="300" flood-color="red" flood-opacity=".5"></feFlood>        
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <rect class="bg" x="0" y="0" width="1280" height="600" fill="#EFEFEF"></rect>
    <rect class="elementRect" x="100" y="100" width="300" height="200" filter="url(#filt)"></rect>
    <rect class="elementRect" x="100" y="100" width="300" height="200" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" ></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution that does not require duplicating the object. I would prefer having it done through any in-built `filter` syntax currently unaware to me,